# Fetching from svelte store returns [object, object]

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, sveltekit, svelte-store

When I fetch this array and return it in the HTML I keep getting [object, object] or undefined. Does anyone know if it's because of something I'm not defining in my svelte store?

For now, I'm just trying to get the name from the API.

Here is the "league-store.js"

```
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

export const leagueStore = writable([]);

const fetchLeagues = async () => {
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'API_KEY',
            'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'v3.football.api-sports.io'
        }
    }
    const url = `https://v3.football.api-sports.io/leagues?season=2022`;
    const res = await fetch(url, options);
    const data = await res.json();
    const loadedLeagues = data.response.map((data) => {
        return {
            leagues: data
        }
    });
    leagueStore.set(loadedLeagues);
}
fetchLeagues();
```

The +page.svelte

```
<script>
    import { leagueStore } from "../../stores/league-stores";

    console.log($leagueStore)
</script>

<div class="absolute top-[80px] right-0 w-[85vw] p-6">

    {#each $leagueStore as leagues}
        <p>{leagues}</p>
    {/each}

</div>
```

and lastly the API I'm calling from as an example of the parameters

```
{
    "get": "leagues",
    "parameters": {
        "season": "2022"
    },
    "errors": [],
    "results": 815,
    "paging": {
        "current": 1,
        "total": 1
    },
    "response": [
        {
            "league": {
                "id": 351,
                "name": "4. liga - Divizie B",
                "type": "League",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/351.png"
            },
            "country": {
                "name": "Czech-Republic",
                "code": "CZ",
                "flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/cz.svg"
            },
            "seasons": [
                {
                    "year": 2022,
                    "start": "2022-08-05",
                    "end": "2023-06-10",
                    "current": true,
                    "coverage": {
                        "fixtures": {
                            "events": true,
                            "lineups": false,
                            "statistics_fixtures": false,
                            "statistics_players": false
                        },
                        "standings": true,
                        "players": false,
                        "top_scorers": false,
                        "top_assists": false,
                        "top_cards": false,
                        "injuries": false,
                        "predictions": true,
                        "odds": false
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 const loadedLeagues = data.response.map((data) => {
        return {
            leagues: data
        }
    });
```

Here `data` is an object of this form

```
        {
            "league": {
                "id": 351,
                "name": "4. liga - Divizie B",
                "type": "League",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/351.png"
            },
            "country": {
                "name": "Czech-Republic",
                "code": "CZ",
                "flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/cz.svg"
            },
            ...
        }
```

You could either map this to objects holding only the fields you need or use as is

```
  const res = await fetch(url, options);
  const data = await res.json();
  leagueStore.set(data.response);
```

and access the fields like this

```
<div>

    {#each $leagueStore as league}
        <p>{league.league.name} - {league.country.name}</p>
    {/each}

</div>
```

Since you tagged Sveltekit and are using an API key you might want to move the fetch logic to a `page.server.js` file or endpoint

https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page-page-server-js
https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load
https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#making-fetch-requests
https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server